# How to handle Connection Error in Message Driven Beans?

Tags: oracle, jms, ibm-mq, message-driven-bean

I have a Message Driven Bean listening to MQ Receiver Queue for incoming Messages.
My MDB is implementing MessageListener and overriding OnMessage method, where I can handle any exception related to the received messages.

All the Connection & Queue parameters are in ejb-jar.xml and weblogic-ejb-jar.xml.

So in case of any Connection failure (e.g. MQ is down, I just get Exception in the console).
How should I catch and handle these connection failure related exceptions in MDB? As I have requirement to send Email notifications to Support group in case of such Connection Failures.
I just saw some info about javax.jms.ExceptionListener, but there is no way I could use it for my setup as I don't have direct access to my connectionfactory / connection objects in case of my MDB.

Comment: Is this connecting to IBM MQ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. We are connecting to IBM MQ (AMS) server.